# How TWIG executes if conditionals?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a php snippet in Symfony2 where I say:
If the user exists -> return these data sets in an array to the template
else -> return name=> 'user not found'. Below is the only way this can work if I have in my twig only the variable 'first_name' being used.

Clear Problem Explanation:
If the user doesn't exist in the database, I cannot call user.name, user.username, user.password. Even if the if conditional isn't satisfied, twig still tries to evaluate that inside statement.

What I want to say is:

```
if (user) {

{{ user.name }}<br>
{{ user.username }}<br>
{{ user.password }} <br>

 }

else {
User not found
}
```

However, if the user isn't found, it will still try and execute the DB access from the variable user ... user.name.. etc. How can I fix this?

## PHP Snippet

```
    /**
     * @Route("/login/{username2}/{password2}")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction($username2, $password2)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $respository = $em->getRepository("SchachteUserBundle:user");

        $username = $username2;
        $password = $password2;
        $user = $respository->findOneBy(array("username"=>$username, "password"=>$password));

        if ($user) {
            return array('exists'=>true, 'first_name' => $user->getName(), 'username' => $user->getUserName(), 'password'=>$user->getPassword());
        }

        return array('exists'=>false, 'first_name' => 'USER NOT FOUND', 'username' => 'USER NOT FOUND', 'password'=>'USER NOT FOUND');
    }
}
```

## TWIG

```
{% if exists == true %}

    Hello {{ first_name }}!

{% else %}

    Sorry, that user does not exist!

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear can add some more details specific to your problem ?

Comment: updated the issue explanation

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump($user); die;` right before you do the `if($user){` in the controller.  You can see what value it has. Most likely it is an object.

Comment: `$user->getPassword()`-> no.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply inject the return of your findOneBy in the template :

```
$user = $respository->findOneBy(array("username"=>$username, "password"=>$password));
return array('user'=>user);
```

Then in the template

```
{% if user %}
    {{ user.name }}<br>
    {{ user.username }}<br>
    {{ user.password }}
{% else %}
    User not found
{% endif %}
```

Moreover if you query the database with a password it means you have stored the clear password. It is very bad practice.